# Include several partials in a wordpress template. Showing only one of them

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have built a template and two partials in Wordpress (php). In the template I use get_template_part() two times but only the first one is loaded.

```
    <div class="partial_blockarticle">
        <?php
          get_template_part('partials/blockarticle');
        ?>
    </div> 
    <div class="partial_interview">
        <?php
          get_template_part('partials/interviewpartial');
        ?>
    </div>
```

In this example, the blockarticles are loaded but no interview. If I switch the divs, only interviews are loaded.

The blockarticles/interviews are Custom Fields and are loaded in the partials like this:

```
    <?php
    $pageID = $post->ID;
    // Build WP_Query() argument array

        $news = new WP_Query(array(
            'posts_per_page' => 6,
            'post_type' => 'blockarticles',
            'order' => 'desc',
            'orderby' => 'date',
            'meta_key' => 'blockarticle_page_parent',
            'meta_value' => $pageID 
        ));
        while($news->have_posts()): $news->the_post();
    ?>
    //Do stuff
```

What am I doing wrong here? $news can not be empty since it shows both articles and interview when I switch place?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try running `wp_reset_query()` directly after the endwhile for both of the custom queries. I assume the problem is that the `$post->ID`in the second include does not return the correct page ID.

Answer (score 2):

Try and call `wp_reset_query()` before instantiating the new WP_Query instances. Sometimes I've had to do this to get additional WP_Queries working properly.

Also try to echo something right before the new WP_Query in each partial. If it echoes properly, the template loading is working propely. E.g.:

```
<?php
// Test echo
echo 'does this work?';

$pageID = $post->ID;
// Build WP_Query() argument array

    $news = new WP_Query(array(
        'posts_per_page' => 6,
        'post_type' => 'blockarticles',
        'order' => 'desc',
        'orderby' => 'date',
        'meta_key' => 'blockarticle_page_parent',
        'meta_value' => $pageID 
    ));
    while($news->have_posts()): $news->the_post();
?>
//Do stuff
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately this did not work. The echos worked.